# Animated lissajous curve not visible python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am very new to animating in python so please bear with me.
So I am trying to make this Lissajous curve animate like the one on [this website](https://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/html5/lis/lissa5.htm)

I do have code of the lissajous curve stationary if needed. I thought by changing the `pi/2` (in the code it's `f`) to be smaller and bigger would replicate it but the graph doesn't appear. Thank you in advance.

Attempt:

```py
# Import our modules 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

a= 1
A = 1
B = 1
b = 3
c = 1
D = 1
fig = plt.figure() 
f=3.14/2
while f > -3.14/2:
    f-=1
xdata, ydata = [], []

ax = plt.gca()
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
def init():
    line.set_data([], []) 
    return line, 
def animate(i):
    t = 0.1*i 

    x = A*np.sin(a*t+f) + c
    y = B*np.sin(b*t) + D
    xdata.append(x) 
    ydata.append(y) 
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata) 

   # ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:black')
    return line,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
anim.save('abclogo.gif', writer='pillow')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the axes limits

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim(0,2)
ax.set_ylim(0,2)
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
```

Alternately, and slightly more efficient would be to not use append inside the animate function by doing the following:

```
# Import our modules 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
a= 1
A = 1
B = 1
b = 3
c = 1
D = 1

f=3.14/2
while f > -3.14/2:
    f-=1

seq=np.arange(0,200,1)
x = A*np.sin(a*0.1*seq+f) + c
y = B*np.sin(b*0.1*seq) + D
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
line, = ax.plot(x, y, color='k')

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
    return line,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(x),interval=25, blit=True)
anim.save('abclogo.gif', writer='imagemagick')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit 2:

`FuncAnimation` doesn't offer a lot of control. For e.g. you won't be able to access axes elements and modify them. You can achieve better control by making use of for loop as shown here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
###initializing the parameters##################
M=1
N=2
########setup the plot################
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
t = np.arange(0, 1000, 1)
x = np.sin(M*0.1*t) 
y = np.sin(N*0.1*t+math.pi/2.0)
ax.set_xlim(-1.25,1.25)
ax.set_ylim(-1.25,1.25)
##################

for i in t:
    phi=np.arange(0,10*math.pi,math.pi/50.)
    #phase shifting to give the impression of rotation
    y = np.sin(N*0.1*t+phi[i])
    line, = ax.plot(x[:i],y[:i],c='black')
    plt.pause(0.01)
    #remove the track
    line.remove()
    del line
```

The animation is shown [here](https://gph.is/g/ZkB3v0B)

Comment: I don't think you saw the website. The animation is meant to look like the graph is rotating.